# Comparing two lists of class objects similar to a Diff Tool

Tags: c#, linq

My requirement is to write a program that sort of mimics diff tools. Yes there are quite a few libraries and open source code that accomplishes this purpose, but I would like to write my own comparer.

Here's the starting point. I have a class called `DataItem` which looks like this:

```
public class DataItem
{
    public DataItem() { }
    public DataItem(string d, string v) { Data = d; Value = v; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have two lists of these class objects, let's call them PRE and POST and take some example values as follows. 'Data' part will be unique in a list.

```
preList: (Data,Value)
AAA,0
BBB,1
CCC,3
DDD,4
FFF,0
GGG,3

postList: (Data,Value)
AAA,0
BBB,2
DDD,4
EEE,9
FFF,3
```

Think of PRE as the original list, and POST as the list after some changes done. I would like to compare the two, and categorize them into three categories:

1. Added Items - An item with a new 'Data' added to the list.
2. Removed Items - An item was removed from the list.
3. Diff Items - 'Data' is found in both PRE and POST lists, but their corresponding 'Value' is different.

So when categorized they should look like this:

```
Added Items:
EEE,9

Removed Items:
CCC,3
GGG,3

Diff Items:
BBB
FFF
```

I have another `DiffItem` class, to objects of which I would like to put the final results. `DiffItem` looks like this:

```
public class DiffItem
{
    public DiffItem() { }
    public DiffItem(string data, string type, string pre, string post) { Data = data; DiffType = type; PreVal = pre; PostVal = post; }

    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string DiffType { get; set; } // DiffType = Add/Remove/Diff
    public string PreVal { get; set; } // preList value corresponding to Data item
    public string PostVal { get; set; } // postList value corresponding to Data item
}
```

To accomplish this, first I extended IEqualityComparer and wrote a couple of comparers:

```
public class DataItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataItem>
{
    public bool Equals(DataItem x, DataItem y)
    {
        return (string.Equals(x.Data, y.Data) && string.Equals(x.Value, y.Value));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataItem obj)
    {
        return obj.Data.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class DataItemDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataItem>
{
    public bool Equals(DataItem x, DataItem y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x.Data, y.Data);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataItem obj)
    {
        return obj.Data.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then use the `Except()` and `Intersect()` methods as follows:

```
    static void DoDiff()
    {
        diffList = new List<DiffItem>();

        IEnumerable<DataItem> preOnly = preList.Except(postList, new DataItemComparer());
        IEnumerable<DataItem> postOnly = postList.Except(preList, new DataItemComparer());
        IEnumerable<DataItem> common = postList.Intersect(preList, new DataItemComparer());

        IEnumerable<DataItem> added = postOnly.Except(preOnly, new DataItemDataComparer());
        IEnumerable<DataItem> removed = preOnly.Except(postOnly, new DataItemDataComparer());
        IEnumerable<DataItem> diffPre = preOnly.Intersect(postOnly, new DataItemDataComparer());
        IEnumerable<DataItem> diffPost = postOnly.Intersect(preOnly, new DataItemDataComparer());

        foreach (DataItem add in added)
        {
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem(add.Data, "Add", null, add.Value));
        }
        foreach (DataItem rem in removed)
        {
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem(rem.Data, "Remove", rem.Value, null));
        }
        foreach (DataItem pre in diffPre)
        {
            DataItem post = diffPost.First(x => x.Data == pre.Data);
            diffList.Add(new DiffItem(pre.Data, "Diff", pre.Value, post.Value));
        }
    }
```

This does work and gets the job done. But I'm wondering if there's a 'better' way to do this. Note that I put quotes around the word 'better', because I don't have a proper definition for what would make this better. Perhaps there is a way to get this done without as many `foreach` loops and use of `Except()` and `Intersect()`, since I would imagine that behind the Linq there's quite a lot of iteration going on.

Simply put, is there cleaner code that I can write for this? I'm asking mostly out of academic interest and to expand my knowledge.

Comment: In your `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods, you should account for one or both of the objects being null, for example: `return string.Equals(x?.Data, y?.Data);`

Comment: `DiffType` should be of enum type rather than `string`. `enum DiffType { Add, Remove, Diff }`

Comment: You could just sort the two on key and make a pass but that would be a whole new approach and not really a code review.

Comment: If `DataItem` class implemented `IComparable<DataItem>` and `IEquatable<DataItem>`, you wouldn't need the `DataItemComparer` class and could omit all the noisy `new DataItemComparer()` parameters.

Comment: A couple of questions: Does order matter? Are you saying that `Data`, e.g. `"AAA"`. is unique in each list?

Comment: @Maxim I agree. I first posted this in SO, but was directed here, so I actually posted a crude code. But yea, should make the change.

Comment: @RickDavin could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: @RobH Order doesn't matter, and yes, every single Data items such as AAA unique in each list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion many lines with `IEnumerable<DataItem>` on the left side make this code noisy. This

```
var preOnly = preList.Except(postList, new DataItemComparer());
var postOnly = postList.Except(preList, new DataItemComparer());
var common = postList.Intersect(preList, new DataItemComparer());
```

is clearer as for me.

As I said in comments you should use enum for `DiffType` instead of string.

```
public enum DiffType
{
    Add,
    Remove,
    Diff
}

public class DiffItem
{
    public DiffItem()
    {
    }

    public DiffItem(string data, DiffType type, string pre, string post)
    {
        Data = data;
        DiffType = type;
        PreVal = pre;
        PostVal = post;
    }

    public DiffType DiffType { get; set; }
}
```

Using `AddRange` method of the `List` this code

> ```
> foreach (DataItem add in added)
> {
>     diffList.Add(new DiffItem(add.Data, "Add", null, add.Value));
> }
> foreach (DataItem rem in removed)
> {
>     diffList.Add(new DiffItem(rem.Data, "Remove", rem.Value, null));
> }
> foreach (DataItem pre in diffPre)
> {
>     DataItem post = diffPost.First(x => x.Data == pre.Data);
>     diffList.Add(new DiffItem(pre.Data, "Diff", pre.Value, post.Value));
> }
> ```

can be rewritten as

```
diffList.AddRange(added.Select(i => new DiffItem(i.Data,
                                                 DiffType.Add,
                                                 null,
                                                 i.Value)));
diffList.AddRange(removed.Select(i => new DiffItem(i.Data,
                                                   DiffType.Remove,
                                                   i.Value,
                                                   null)));
diffList.AddRange(diffPre.Select(i => new DiffItem(i.Data,
                                                   DiffType.Diff,
                                                   i.Value,
                                                   diffPost.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Data == i.Data)?.Value)));
```

And I believe an instance of the `DiffItem` should be immutable so setters of the properties can be removed.

Also instead of using `DiffType` you can create three subclasses representing each type of difference:

```
public class DiffItem
{
    public DiffItem()
    {
    }

    public DiffItem(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public string Data { get; }
} 

public sealed class Addition : DiffItem { ... }
public sealed class Deletion : DiffItem { ... }
public sealed class Difference : DiffItem { ... }
```

It will allow to eliminate some constructor parameters that are useless for particular difference type.

Comment: When you say using var over IEnumerable<DataItem>, is there a specific advantage to doing that, or is it solely for improving readability? It's just one of those habits that I never got used to using var, and prefer using strongly typed variables, but I do agree using var is cleaner.

Using AddRange() definitely improves readability.

And I like what you did with DiffItem, never thought of going that far but it's definitely very clean and efficient.

Comment: @Sach In this case `var` stands only for readability. There are cases where `var` **must** be used (for anonymous types). Four years ago I had your habit too and wasn't using `var`, and now I don't understand why :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is cleaner but it is another approach.

> Perhaps is there a way to get this done without as many 'foreach'
>   loops and use of Except() and Intersetc()

It is probably more efficient and I like it better but I like seeing logic loops.
I left debug statements as **not fully tested**.

```
public static void ListDiff2()
{
    List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "AAA", "BBB", "DDD" };
    List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "AAA", "CCC" };
    //List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "FFF", "GGG" };
    //List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "AAA", "BBB", "DDD", "FFF", "EEE" };

    IEnumerable<string> listAsorted = listA.OrderBy(x => x);
    IEnumerable<string> listBsorted = listB.OrderBy(x => x);

    var listAenumerator = listAsorted.GetEnumerator();
    var listBenumerator = listBsorted.GetEnumerator();

    bool listAcanmove = listAenumerator.MoveNext();
    bool listBcanmove = listBenumerator.MoveNext();

    while (listAcanmove | listBcanmove)
    {
        string valueA = listAenumerator.Current;
        string valueB = listBenumerator.Current;

        Debug.WriteLine($"valueA = {valueA}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"valueB = {valueB}");

        if (!listAcanmove && listBcanmove)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{valueB} in B not in A");
            listBcanmove = listBenumerator.MoveNext();
        }
        if (listAcanmove && !listBcanmove)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{valueA} in A not in B");
            listAcanmove = listAenumerator.MoveNext();
        }
        else
        {
            int comp = string.Compare(valueA, valueB);
            if (comp == -1)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{valueA} in A not in B");
                listAcanmove = listAenumerator.MoveNext();
            }
            else if (comp == 1)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{valueB} in B not in A");
                listBcanmove = listBenumerator.MoveNext();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{valueA} {valueB} in B and A");

                //perform value comparison here

                listAcanmove = listAenumerator.MoveNext();
                listBcanmove = listBenumerator.MoveNext();
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
    Debug.WriteLine($"done");
}
```

Comment: thanks. This looks like a more generic approach though, and does not quite solve my situation? Instead of two List<string> lists I want to do the comparison on class objects, and I want both Data and Value parts to be available for future use once comparisons are done.

Comment: @Sach Look again, it solves your situation.  Just substitute DataItem for string and do a little work.    See "//perform value comparison here".  It does exactly what you asked for "get this done without as many 'foreach' loops and use of Except() and Intersetc()".

Comment: OK I got it now. Yes it's a different approach, thanks. I will implement this too and see.